# Why NestJs cron works incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I have such a function

```js
  @Cron('*/5 * * * * *')
  testCron() {
    console.log('cron');
  }
```

I assume that it should print the console every 5 seconds, but instead it prints 3 messages every 5 seconds. What am I doing wrong?

```js
  @Cron('*/5 * * * * *')
  testCron() {
    console.log('cron');
  }
```

Comment: Likely the function is being imported three times.

Comment: Share a [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than likely, you have three instances of the class with this `@Cron()` decorator. This can happen when you add the provider to *multiple* `providers` arrays instead of sharing the singleton instance through the module it originated from.

When you have `FooService` and want to use it in `BarModule`, your `FooModule` should have `FooService` in **both** the `providers` and the `exports` arrays. Then, `BarModule` can add `FooModule` to its `imports` array, and then`BarController` and `BarService` will now have access to `FooServic` due.

```js
@Module({
  providers: [FooService],
  exports: [FooService]
})
export class FooModule {}
```

```js
@Module({
  imports: [FooModule],
  controllers: [BarController],
  providers: [BarService],
})
export class BarModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should name your cron, like this:

```
 @Cron('*/5 * * * * *',{name:'yourCronName'})
  testCron() {
    console.log('cron');
  }
```

Comment: The answer from @Jay McDoniel solves my problem, but this option also works, thanks!