# nestjs cron runs twice or throwing duplicate job name running

Tags: javascript, cron, nestjs, scheduled-tasks

I had `@Cron()` working before but now I'm trying to add the usage of environment variable instead of giving it a static time.  I have read quite a few posts such as

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/task-scheduling

https://medium.com/@sangimed/nestjs-externalize-cron-expressions-in-a-env-file-ca09d3cb2bec

[NestJs Using Environment Configuration on @Cron decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69463692/nestjs-using-environment-configuration-on-cron-decorator)

[passing variable from config service into Typescript decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59698240/passing-variable-from-config-service-into-typescript-decorator)

but I am still not able to get it running properly.  I even copied the samples directly from those posts and try but still I either have duplicate cronjob running or it'll throw an error saying duplicated cronjob name..

my sample code below which would run twice

```js
  onModuleInit() {
    this.addCronJob('coffee-party', '30');
  }

  makeCoffee() {
    this.logger.warn('coffee or tea');
  }

  addCronJob(name: string, seconds: string) {
    const job = new CronJob(`*/${seconds} * * * * *`, () => {
      this.makeCoffee();
    });

    // this.schedulerRegistry.addCronJob(name, job); // will throw error if uncommented
    job.start();

    this.logger.warn(
      `job ${name} added for each minute at ${seconds} seconds!`,
    );
  }
```

result of the above would look like

```js
[Nest] 67802  - 11/01/2023, 11:29:00 AM    WARN [CoffeeService] coffee or tea
[Nest] 67802  - 11/01/2023, 11:29:00 AM    WARN [CoffeeService] coffee or tea
```

If I uncomment `schedulerRegistry` and add it into the code, it would throw error.  The code would look like

```js
  onModuleInit() {
    this.addCronJob('coffee-party', '30');
  }

  makeCoffee() {
    this.logger.warn('coffee or tea');
  }

  addCronJob(name: string, seconds: string) {
    const job = new CronJob(`*/${seconds} * * * * *`, () => {
      this.makeCoffee();
    });

    this.schedulerRegistry.addCronJob(name, job);
    job.start();

    this.logger.warn(
      `job ${name} added for each minute at ${seconds} seconds!`,
    );
  }
```

result of the above would throw an error like this

```js
/node_modules/@nestjs/schedule/dist/scheduler.registry.js:56
            throw new Error((0, schedule_messages_1.DUPLICATE_SCHEDULER)('Cron Job', name));
                  ^
Error: Cron Job with the given name (coffee-party) already exists. Ignored.
    at SchedulerRegistry.addCronJob
```

I was using `@Cron()` before and it was doing duplicate runs too but after adding the `name` attributes then it works fine, So my setup shouldn't be any problem at all.

Just that `@Cron()` cannot use environment variable directly that's why I am searching around and changing the code to what others suggested.

Please can someone give me some advices / suggestions, thank you so much in advance.

Comment: maybe the advance is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77118231/12599279